# Issue with executing overload stored procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE shop_query_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE shop_info_pp
    (p_id IN bb_shopper.idshopper%TYPE, 
     p_firstname OUT bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE,
     p_city OUT bb_shopper.city%TYPE,
     p_state OUT bb_shopper.state%TYPE,
     p_phone OUT bb_shopper.phone%TYPE,
     p_email OUT bb_shopper.email%TYPE);
  PROCEDURE shop_info_pp
    (p_id IN bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE, 
     p_firstname OUT bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE,
     p_city OUT bb_shopper.city%TYPE,
     p_state OUT bb_shopper.state%TYPE,
     p_phone OUT bb_shopper.phone%TYPE,
     p_email OUT bb_shopper.email%TYPE);
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY shop_query_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE shop_info_pp
    (p_id IN bb_shopper.idshopper%TYPE, 
     p_firstname OUT bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE,
     p_city OUT bb_shopper.city%TYPE,
     p_state OUT bb_shopper.state%TYPE,
     p_phone OUT bb_shopper.phone%TYPE,
     p_email OUT bb_shopper.email%TYPE)
  IS
    BEGIN
      SELECT firstname, city, state, phone, email
      INTO p_firstname, p_city, p_state, p_phone, p_email
      FROM bb_shopper
      WHERE idshopper = p_id;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID does not exist');
   END;    
   PROCEDURE shop_info_pp
    (p_id IN bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE, 
     p_firstname OUT bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE,
     p_city OUT bb_shopper.city%TYPE,
     p_state OUT bb_shopper.state%TYPE,
     p_phone OUT bb_shopper.phone%TYPE,
     p_email OUT bb_shopper.email%TYPE)
  IS
    BEGIN
      SELECT firstname, city, state, phone, email
      INTO p_firstname, p_city, p_state, p_phone, p_email
      FROM bb_shopper
      WHERE lastname = p_id;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last name does not exist');
  END;
END;
```

However when I try to execute my procedure using this code:

```
VARIABLE g_fname VARCHAR2
VARIABLE g_city VARCHAR2
VARIABLE g_state VARCHAR2
VARIABLE g_phone VARCHAR2
VARIABLE g_email VARCHAR2

 EXECUTE shop_query_pkg.shop_info_pp(23, :g_fname, :g_city, :g_state, :g_phone, :g_email);

PRINT :g_fname
PRINT :g_city
PRINT :g_state
PRINT :g_phone
PRINT :g_email
```

I get this error message:

```
BEGIN shop_query_pkg.shop_info_pp(23, :g_fname, :g_city, :g_state, :g_phone, :g_email); END;

*
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error 
ORA-06512: at "S36.SHOP_QUERY_PKG", line 11 
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I think it something wrong with my select statement, but I keep checking it and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Here is the DESC bb_shopper:

```
Name    Null?   Type
IDSHOPPER   NOT NULL    NUMBER(4)
FIRSTNAME       VARCHAR2(15)
LASTNAME        VARCHAR2(20)
ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(40)
CITY        VARCHAR2(20)
STATE       CHAR(2)
ZIPCODE     VARCHAR2(15)
PHONE       VARCHAR2(10)
FAX     VARCHAR2(10)
EMAIL       VARCHAR2(25)
USERNAME        VARCHAR2(8)
PASSWORD        VARCHAR2(8)
COOKIE      NUMBER(4)
DTENTERED       DATE
PROVINCE        VARCHAR2(15)
COUNTRY     VARCHAR2(15)
PROMO       CHAR(1)
```

Yes I've tried changing state to CHAR and I get the same message.

Comment: You'll need to fully describe your `bb_shopper` table.  Columns, data types, etc.

Comment: Think I figured it out, I don't understand why but I had to use an anonymous block to execute it.

Comment: What is the difference between first and second versions of your procedure? Overloaded procedure need to have different signature - at least one of parameters need to be different type/name.

Answer (score 0):

You must fully specify the VARIABLE types and add the maximum varchar2 sizes.

If you use the following block, it works as expected:

```
VARIABLE g_fname VARCHAR2(60)
VARIABLE g_city  VARCHAR2(60)
VARIABLE g_state VARCHAR2(60)
VARIABLE g_phone VARCHAR2(60)
VARIABLE g_email VARCHAR2(60)

EXECUTE shop_query_pkg.shop_info_pp(23, :g_fname, :g_city, :g_state, :g_phone, :g_email);

PRINT :g_fname
PRINT :g_city
PRINT :g_state
PRINT :g_phone
PRINT :g_email
```